# Configuring Bluetooth Codecs

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

What I am attempting to do: get my laptop to send audio to headphones that support AAC over Bluetooth.

I went through [a good amount of trouble](https://pandasauce.org/post/bluetooth-on-linux/) to get Bluetooth audio to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in general. Now that it works, this is the HCI dump I get:

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.37
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0x400
> AVDTP(s): Discover cmd: transaction 1 nsp 0x00
< AVDTP(s): Discover rsp: transaction 1 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1 - Audio Source
    ACP SEID 2 - Audio Sink
> AVDTP(s): All Capabilities cmd: transaction 2 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1
< AVDTP(s): All Capabilities rsp: transaction 2 nsp 0x00
    Media Transport
    Media Codec - SBC
      16kHz 32kHz 44.1kHz 48kHz 
      Mono DualChannel Stereo JointStereo 
      4 8 12 16 Blocks
      4 8 Subbands
      SNR Loudness 
      Bitpool Range 2-64
    Delay Reporting
> AVDTP(s): All Capabilities cmd: transaction 3 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 2
< AVDTP(s): All Capabilities rsp: transaction 3 nsp 0x00
    Media Transport
    Media Codec - SBC
      16kHz 32kHz 44.1kHz 48kHz 
      Mono DualChannel Stereo JointStereo 
      4 8 12 16 Blocks
      4 8 Subbands
      SNR Loudness 
      Bitpool Range 2-64
    Delay Reporting
> AVDTP(s): All Capabilities cmd: transaction 4 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1
< AVDTP(s): All Capabilities rsp: transaction 4 nsp 0x00
    Media Transport
    Media Codec - SBC
      16kHz 32kHz 44.1kHz 48kHz 
      Mono DualChannel Stereo JointStereo 
      4 8 12 16 Blocks
      4 8 Subbands
      SNR Loudness 
      Bitpool Range 2-64
    Delay Reporting
> AVDTP(s): Set config cmd: transaction 5 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1 - INT SEID 1
    Media Transport
    Media Codec - SBC
      44.1kHz 
      JointStereo 
      16 Blocks
      8 Subbands
      Loudness 
      Bitpool Range 2-53
    Delay Reporting
< AVDTP(s): Set config rsp: transaction 5 nsp 0x00
> AVDTP(s): Delay Report cmd: transaction 6 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1 delay 150.0ms
< AVDTP(s): Delay Report rsp: transaction 6 nsp 0x00
> AVDTP(s): Open cmd: transaction 7 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1
< AVDTP(s): Open rsp: transaction 7 nsp 0x00
< AVDTP(s): Start cmd: transaction 14 nsp 0x00
    ACP SEID 1
> AVDTP(s): Start rsp: transaction 14 nsp 0x00
< AVDTP(m): ver 2 cc 0 pt 1 seqn 0 time 0 ssrc 1
```

From here I see that it ends up using SBC and MPEG24/AAC never even gets mentioned. The headphones (Bose QC35) definitely support it.

I tried googling, but it seems that Bluetooth codec configuration on Linux is not something that has any coverage at all. The only thing I managed to find is [evidence](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blame/master/profiles/audio/a2dp-codecs.h#L27) that BlueZ has supported MPEG24/AAC for a few years now. Can anyone suggest directions for how to enable MPEG24/AAC for a Bluetooth connection?